# Лицензия Windows (как ее проверить)

Tags: windows, лицензирование

Покупаем ноутбуки на государственной площадке. Есть вопросы по лицензиям. В документации у нас прописано "предустановленная лицензионная операционная система (ОС) с бесплатными обновлениями Microsoft Windows 10 Professiona". -- Это же может быть как EOM так и коробке, электронный ключ?

Не понимаю такие вещи. Есть официальные дистрибьюторы Microsoft, которые могут дать возможность поставлять лицензию производителям. То-есть эти ноутбуки будут точно лицензированы, так как все вроде официально.

Но дистрибьюторами работают не все, как по другому они получают EOM лицензию? И здесь шанс попасть в пиратку увеличивается. Какие документы и действия могут подтвердить, что поставщик даст нам настоящее лицензированное ПО?

Как нам 100% проверить лицензию на ноутбуках, после их поставки????

Comment: Вы путаете наличие лицензии и легитимную активацию.

Comment: @Akina а разве это не одно и то же? если есть лицензия то и будет нормальная активация, но если лицензии нету - то будет поставлена пиратка

Comment: *если лицензии нету - то будет поставлена пиратка* Если есть лицензия (подтверждаемая, например, наклейкой на корпусе), но стоит пиратка, соответствующая лицензии либо перекрываемая лицензией в порядке даунгрейда - никаких претензий по поводу нелицензионности к Вам нет.

Comment: @Akina  а как проверить лицензию?)

Comment: Осмотреть корпус на предмет наличия наклейки. Изучить её на наличие признаков отсутствия подделки и ненарушения защиты. Убедиться, что она соответствует составу приобретённого оборудования и программного обеспечения из контракта.

Comment: @Akina ну там только голограмма, изменение цвета и надпись Windows. А как понять что она соответствует составу приобретённого оборудования и программного обеспечения из контракта ?

Comment: Ну как бы в контрактах имеет место быть приложение с детальным списком приобретаемого. Акты приёмки опять же... Обратитесь в бухгалтерию.

Comment: @Akina Ну мы же говорим об "предустановленная лицензионная операционная система Microsoft Windows 10 Professiona" на ноутбуке. Проверить можно только по наклейке получается?)

Comment: Детский сад... https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/howtotell/default.aspx?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0 https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/howtotell/hardware-pc-purchase

Comment: @Akina Скажите пожалуйста)) какие документы мы должны попросить у поставщика, чтобы убедится в том что будет установлено лицензионное ПО ?

Comment: Думаю, для получения ответа на этот вопрос следует озадачить вашего юриста - пусть свяжется с представительством Майкрософт или их партнёром по вопросам лицензирования и получит всю необходимую информацию. А вы будете помогать ему формулировать вопросы и определять полноту этой информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно проверить через настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот где можно увидеть статус:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же [вот](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-learn-copy-windows-7-windows-8-activated) есть разные способы проверки. В командной строке можно ввести команду:

```
slmgr /dli
```

и увидеть что-то типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-determine-if-license-oem-retail-volume-windows-10) способ через командную строку.

Comment: Да, это я видела, но думаю им не составит труда, сделать так, чтобы там показывало то что нужно)

Comment: Очень сильно сомневаюсь) есть несколько мест которые должны отображать статус лицензии, чтобы это изменить нужно хорошо покопаться) это не стоит того как мне кажется но я могу ошибаться)

Comment: Т.е. ты хочешь сказать, что цировая активация с помощью активатора скачанного с рутрекера сделает мою винду лицензионной на столько, что отдел "К" ко мне не прикопается?